# Is there any task where classical computers outperform quantum computers?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing, time-complexity

Everybody knows that there are whole classes of problems which quantum computers are able to solve much faster (i.e. with fewer instructions) than classical computers.

Is there any problem for which the reverse is true?

Comment: ??? Anyone care to explain the downvotes? What is wrong with this question?

Comment: Perhaps it is because Quantum Computers do not yet exist. Also, the very nature of the two computers cannot be compared on a per instruction basis.

Comment: @Dave: you can definitely compare classical computers with quantum ones on a per-instruction basis. Quantum computers are likely to be slower per instruction, but that doesn't stop you from counting steps and making the comparison. There seems to be a rash of downvoting new user's questions with no explanation, where it's not obvious to me why. See [this question I just asked on meta](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/drive-by-downvoting-on-new-users-questions). I find this very disturbing.

Comment: @Peter, if we are talking about mathematical models then I think the common models of quantum computation are generalizations of the standard classical model, isn't that the case? And if we are talking about real quantum computers then I think Dave's comment is valid.

Comment: Yes, but quantum computers are only allowed reversible classical operations, and it's not completely obvious that classical reversible computation isn't much slower than classical computation. (You need to use a non-obvious theorem of Charles Bennett to prove this.) Furthermore, if you only have limited memory available, it's not true ... there seem to be computations which can be done quite a bit more quickly with irreversible computation given limited space.

Comment: I've voted the question up because I'd like to read answers, and because Peter Friggin' Shor thinks it's worthwhile.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I just speculated about possible downvotes. I'm happy to have learnt something new.

Comment: one of those unintentionally deep questions suggesting not much background/research in the area by the poster as phrased, but think its definitely a research level _question_. formally, basically close to the BQP$\stackrel{?}{=}$P question. informally, related to the [DWave controversy](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=d-waves-quantum-computer-courts-controversy) and maybe related to downvotes/close vote.

Comment: Although I did not vote yet one way or the other, I don't think this is a good question since BPTIME(f(n)) \subseteq BQTIME(f(n)) is clear. If the OP has different computational model(s) in mind, then he should have specified them.

Comment: To clarify: My question is about _theoretical_ quantum computers, not practical ones (which are obviously not "practical" yet). I know nothing about quantum computers beyond what I have picked up from the popular media, so if the answer is "clear" in any way, I would really appreciate a short explanation for why that is so. That is all I was asking for.

Comment: @huck [BPTime(f(n))](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo2#bptime) $\subseteq$ [BQTIME(f(n))](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo2#bqtime) does not seem to be stated in the complexity zoo. ref? maybe an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're asking whether a quantum computer can compute any function that a classical computer can compute without using many more elementary computational *steps*, then the answer is yes: a quantum computer can perform any reversible classical computation, and if you keep the input around, any classical computation can be made reversible at a cost of multiplying the number of steps by a small constant factor.

If you're asking whether a quantum computer can compute any function that a classical computer can without using many more *resources,* the answer is much less clear. The construction that lets you make a $T$-step computation reversible using $O(T)$ steps also takes $O(T)$ space (i.e., memory cells). You can achieve a smaller blow-up in space at the cost of a superlinear number of steps. See [Time/Space Trade-Offs for Reversible Computation](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=73186) by Charles H. Bennett.

For an actual physical quantum computer, it's very likely that you might also be able to make it faithfully simulate a classical computer by letting it lose coherence, but in this case it's no longer really working as a quantum computer, and if you try to use a quantum computer that is operating this way as a subroutine in a quantum computation, it might not work properly.

Comment: Exactly the kind of information I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_IaVepNDT4
check it out, that guy explains your question. He starts with the concept of a qbit and around the 5:15 mark he goes into what you asked.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The video was very interesting, but AFAICS starting at 5:15 what he actually explains is that superposition doesn't help all algorithms (i.e. quantum algorithms are not at an advantage everywhere), rather than that quantum algorithms are at a *disadvantage* for some problems.